# How can I disable the hint window in EClipse

Tags: eclipse

When I hover over some type,etc in eclipse it shows a big yellow hint box for it and shows the information of the type, what it is used for,...you know that yellowish hint box that appears..well that is certainly good info to know but it gets very annoying, whenever I click on some line of code in eclipse it shows my this yellow hint box that covers half of my codes and i cannot even read them until i press another key to get rid of it...is there a way I can change the default behavior of eclipse so it does Not show that by default and it only shows it when I want it to show like pressing the combination of some keys that I define for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java code, there are preference settings for this:

```
Window | Preferences | Java | Editor | Hovers
```

You can disable the hovers you don't want, such as any that are checked but don't have a modifier key assigned.  Alternatively, you can assign modifier keys to the ones you like/use so they only appear when hovering while that key is pressed.

Comment: thanks, I was there but could not find the right one to disable this, which one is it?

Comment: Uncheck the hovers that don't have modifier keys.  That will prevent the hovers from appearing "unsolicited".